# Ctrl-C doesn't always terminate a shell script

Tags: bash, docker

I have two scenarios:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
  
sleep infinity
# When I type Ctrl-C here, "sleep" command and script are stopped so I didn't see "End"

echo End
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
  
docker exec container-id sleep infinity
# When I type Ctrl-C here, "docker exec" command is stopped but script continued so I saw "End"

echo End
```

Why the difference in behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's how bash behaves when its process group receives a SIGINT but the program currently running on the foreground terminates normally.

The rationale for this behavior is given [here](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2017-08/msg00006.html) as follows:

> The basic idea is that the user intends a keyboard-generated SIGINT to go
> to the foreground process; that process gets to decide how to handle it;
> and bash reacts accordingly.  If the process dies to due SIGINT, bash acts
> as if it received the SIGINT; if it does not, bash assumes the process
> handled it and effectively ignores it.
>
> Consider a process (emacs is the usual example) that uses SIGINT for its
> own purposes as a normal part of operation. If you run that program in a
> script, you don't want the shell aborting the script unexpectedly as a
> result.